# How do I change the latency for my SQLPlus session

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, latency

I'm trying to change my latency for my SQLPlus version 10.2.0.4.0 session. From what I can see, I need to add these parameters to my SQLNET.ora file:

```
SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=1000
SQLNET.OUTBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=1000
SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT=1000
SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT=1000
TCP.CONNECT_TIMEOUT=1000
SQLNET.RECV_BUF_SIZE=1
```

But no matter what I change these values to, when I try to run a query and connect/disconnect from my internet connection, I do not see a difference. Is there something else I need to change or restart? Please advise.

Comment: You are changing the timeout values; why do you think that any of those settings would change the latency? Why do you even want to change the latency? Are you trying to make the queries slower to simulate a slow connection?

Comment: You can't improve latency by tweaking `sqlnet.ora` settings. How are you experiencing slowness? A query that takes a long time to return? A query returning millions of rows and it takes a long time to write them to a file? A shell loop invoking sqlplus many times to get single rows? There's probably a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I thought this was what is needed to change the latency. If it is not, please advise what I can do to change the latency.

My goal is actually to fix a client's PC issue. He is using our program, and the program errors out sometimes because the network he is on goes down periodically. I thought if I changed the latency on his PC, the program would stay up longer.